# Why isn't my comparison based replacement working in this forEach?

Tags: javascript

I want to retain the array instead of creating a new one (which map does), hence, I'm doing the following using forEach. But none of my comparisons are going through and the array remains the same.

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];

array1.forEach(element =>  element < 2 ? 0 : element);
//array1.forEach(element =>  element + 2);
console.log(array1);
```

The result should be array1 = [0, 2, 3];

Is my understanding of how it works incorrect?

Comment: `.forEach()` doesn't modify the array. You're probably looking for `.map()`. Do remember that `.map()` returns a new array.

Comment: `array1.forEach((element, idx) =>  { if (element < 2) array1[idx] = 0;
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to modify the original array which may make some conflicts, it would be better to use `map`,

But If this is the only case you need, you can use `forEach` and get the element by its index and reassign it like `element < 2 && (arr[index] = 0)`

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];

array1.forEach((element, index, arr) =>  element < 2 && (arr[index] = 0));

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me what kind of conflicts it might cause?

Comment: @Nikhat, you are welcome, In your simple case it will not make any conflicts, but in other cases, It can make, for example, if you `splice` the array inside the `forEach` because `splice` method can effect the origin array add/remove items.

Answer (score 1):

Use map (and reassign the initial array), or use the `thisArg` argument with `forEach` ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#syntax)). Note: in the `forEach` with `thisArg` the lambda can not be an arrow function (that would not bind `this`):

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = [...array1];
let array3 = [...array1];
let array4 = [...array1];
// remap
array1 = array1.map( el => el < 2 ? 0 : el );

// with foreach, use the 'thisArg' parameter
array2.forEach( function(el, i) { this[i] = this[i] < 2 ? -1 : el }, array2 );

// not advisable, but other possibilities
array3 = array3.filter(el => el < 2).map(_ => -2)
  .concat(array3.filter(el => el >= 2));
array4 = array4.reduce( (acc, el) => [...acc, el < 2 ? -3 : el], [] );
console.log(`[${array1}, [${array2}], [${array3}], [${array4}]`);
```